# How to reliably convert local time to UTC on a Windows machine using C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, time, utc

I need to be able to convert local time to UTC on a Windows machine. I found the [SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API that claims to do this, but then I read its description and found this:

> The SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime function may calculate the local time incorrectly under the following conditions:
>
> - The time zone uses a different UTC offset for the old and new years.
> - The UTC time to be converted and the calculated local time are in different years.

My first rhetorical question to MS, "How difficult is it to write a reliable API?"

And then, the actual question — how do you do it to work in 100% of the times? (And not like that API suggests.)

Comment: Quite hard to work for times in the future, for example

Comment: If only you'd found the function you actually need, instead of its inverse, you might not have thought to ask this question. [`TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725485.aspx) converts "local time to UTC on a Windows machine," and it doesn't mention anything about computing incorrect results.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Yeah, good point. Why would TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime not have this issue?

Comment: Re "How difficult is it to write a reliable API?" If they keep changing the rules on daylight savings... "How difficult is it to keep the same time?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to both your questions is that it is essentially impossible. This is one of the reasons computer science folks tend to *hate* dealing with local time.

Here are some examples of the confounding issues: When we jump back an hour from 2:00 to 1:00, there are two 1:30's. We also have no way to know today what the daylight savings time rules, if any, will be in ten years. Time zone boundaries are sometimes moved, so just knowing that you're in Pacific time today may not be enough to tell us what your time zone offset was 85 years ago. There is no way to know today what leap seconds may or may not be inserted in the future.

If you find yourself in a situation when it is possible, you will have to code in the specific circumstances that make those operations possible in your particular case. The operations provided are generalized and provide "usually correct" results without constraining the cases in which they can be used.

Moral: Don't use local time except for display. And even then, converting times in the past or future into local times is problematic.

Comment: OK, I see your point. I do indeed store all dates/times in UTC but I need them in local time for SetWaitableTimer() API, for instance. So, to re-phrase my question, if I need to do this conversion within, say a year in the future. Would that be reliable?

Comment: Why do you need local time for [`SetWaitableTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289.aspx), Ahmd0? "Be sure to use a UTC-based absolute time, as the system uses UTC-based time internally." And even if the absolute due time *were* in local time, you still wouldn't *need* local time. "Negative values indicate relative time."

Comment: @RobKennedy: Yes, I agree but that is not that easy. 1. My software uses a waiting period that can be specified by a user and I prefer to set it as a "relative time" in case of daylight saving hour skip. 2. The actual date/time comes from a user, and I can't expect them to use UTC. That is why I need to convert.

Comment: When you input a time from a user in local time, convert it into UTC immediately and store it in UTC. About the only exception is recurring events (like "the first tuesday of each month at 2PM local") and, for those, you need a specific "recurring local time" class, because it's special.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yeah, that's what I'm doing, but what really doesn't make me feel at ease is that statement from MSDN that that API can fail. From my experience dealing with MS, I know really well that their APIs can fail when you least expect them to and this one would be a heck of a hard one to diagnose. You see, that is what I'm trying to avoid... and I'm not really fond of using older CRT functions as was suggested below...

Comment: My advice then, unfortunately, would be to use your own functions that do exactly what you need and whose issues, if any, you will thus understand.

Comment: Google `"michkap time"`. Michael Kaplan is a Microsoft blogger who often addresses i18n issues.

Answer (score 3):

Since the DST periods sometimes change in certain areas, it's hard to write something that is correct in all cases, past and future.

Nevertheless, I you need this functionality, I would suggest using the C functions (localtime, mktime, ...).  I recently had a problem where the Windows function SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime did not work correctly on a Citrix server (Citrix does quite some strange (but advanced) things regarding timezones), but the C functions worked correctly.

Comment: The gmtime function on windows says it uses US rules to decide if DST is in effect so I don't think these are trustworthy either.

Comment: I am using the C-time functions (gmtime, mktime, localtime, ...) in my application that is used in multiple countries and continents (Western Europe, Eastern Europen, Russia, US, ...) and it works correctly in all cases.  I think that the C Run Time uses the Windows functions, which use the DST-information stored in the registry to calculate the correct times.